# IntelliJ sees multiple ghost modules in the project

Tags: intellij-idea

I have only one module in the project, named `FilterWidget`. Despite that, `IntelliJ` sees multiple "ghost" copies of it:

[image]

All these modules allow partially separate, partially shared setup, which creates a mess.

What is it and how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not ghost modules; these are modules representing individual source sets in your Gradle project. As described on the [JetBrains Web site](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#gradle), IntelliJ IDEA starting with version 2016.1 creates a separate module for every source set in your Gradle project, in order to correctly resolve dependencies which are only used in one source set.

Comment: Then why it shows 3 modules, not 2? I have default gradle config, so this probably implies 2 sourcesets, is this correct?

Comment: This may be a leftover from a previous import performed using an older version of IntelliJ.